Automatically installing extensions in the Wikibase Suite
I'm attempting to automate some parts of setting up my local Wikibase Docker instance. Currently, if I want to add WikibaseQualityConstraints and WikibaseLexeme (among other actions), I have to run install commands inside the Docker container somewhat manually.
What would be more ideal is to have some kind of script that runs automatically as part of the install process or to be able to modify an install file to perform these actions. Closest answer I could find was to use a wrapper Dockerfile, which I don't think will work since Wikibase Docker instance includes multiple Docker containers that are set up using the command docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.extra.yml up -d.
A wrapper script of some kind would be ideal, since there are other actions I would like to run other than installing extensions (modifying LocalSettings.php, running PHP files inside the main Container, uploading XML, installing and running Python files, etc.) but I'm not sure the best way to go about it or if some pre-existing method is recommended by the Wikibase Suite team or by Docker itself.

There is probably a better answer to this so I'm going to leave this open at the present time, but my work-around so far is to run a Bash script that clones the extensions and then copies them to their respective container.
